# ruby-pg sanitize data before insert

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

Ruby newbie here. I'm trying to insert this string "Lady Arabella's Scandalo..." I'm using ruby-pg to do this. However I'm having erros because of the single quote, how can I sanitize this string and remove all html tags? Is there a built in function for this?

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`escape_string`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:escape_string) to properly escape your single quotes:

```
db = PG.connect(...)
db.exec("insert into t (...) values ('#{db.escape_string(str)}', ...)")
```

or use [`prepare`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:prepare) and [`exec_prepared`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:exec_prepared) to work with a prepared statement instead:

```
db.prepare('ins', 'insert into t (...) values ($1, ...)')
db.exec_prepared('ins', [str, ...])
```

Comment: Thanks. I google and got here. Using `connection.escape_string`.

Comment: @huy Headsup, `connection.escape_string` will not escape a backslash at the end of your field.

Comment: @IslamAzab `escape_string` just calls `PQescapeStringConn` from the PostgreSQL C library so if it doesn't escape a backslash then it doesn't need to. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @muistooshort You are right, the problem would appear if you had something like this `select 'test \'::tsvector;` or `select E'test\';`. Try it.

Comment: @IslamAzab Seems to be working fine for me. Can you provide a compete example of `escape_string` not working properly? And why would you be trying to use the E syntax with a non-literal string? The only time you'd use `E'...'` is if you have to manually enter newlines and such.

Comment: `db.exec("insert into t (...) values ('#{db.escape_string(str)}', ...)")` Also works for MySQL. Very glad I found this post after much searching :)